# Configuring Remote Desktop to NOT force an automatic log off

Tags: windows-8.1, remote-desktop

So, I've never encountered this before, and I have no idea how I achieved it, but googling for help on this issue leads me to believe that I've stumbled on to every IT admins' wet dream (and my worst nightmare). [i.e. I see lots of IT Admins asking how to enable this, but no one asking how to disable this behavior.]

I run a headless Windows 8.1 machine, and I remote into it from time to time and leave it running media "server" applications and such.

The problem is, every time I close Remote Desktop (just closing the RDP window, not logging off, etc.) it forces the computer to be logged off -- I open a new remote desktop session with the same user, and none of the programs are running anymore, it's a fresh desktop, all state is lost, etc.

The behavior I'm expecting (and seeing in every other environment I've ever encountered) is that closing remote desktop is akin to "locking" the PC, all of the applications remain running, etc. -- If I RDP in again, I should be back at the last state I left it in (this is the desired behavior for my scenario).

Any thoughts on where to start troubleshooting this behavior or how to "fix" it?

Thanks!

Comment: Check local/group policies and ensure that no disconnected session timeout polices are set (Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Session Host -> Session Time Limits)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I've set all the time limits to "disabled" -- but it didn't help (prior to that, they were all undefined). -- Also, the issue is not related to time limits, if I close the window, even for less than 5 seconds, and open a new one, it's a fresh session, the old one is gone. -- Also, I can leave RDP open and minimized all day, and it's fine -- I just don't want to have to -- I'm used to closing RDP windows that I'm not using.